# If statements accept anything

Tags: java, if-statement, statements

I am new to Java and programming in general.

In my program, I use if statements to read specific user input. But, when I enter the code
"75832", it processes it as if I entered "24231". Also, if I enter anything besides those numbers, it processes it as if I entered "24231". I've done some other basic programs like this before, but I don't know what I did or am doing wrong.

Any help?

```
static void gateMethod() throws InterruptedException
{

String stageCode;
int randomChunk;

Random generator = new Random();
Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

randomChunk = generator.nextInt(6);
System.out.println("Welcome to Datahub v.1");
System.out.println("\rEnter a phrase or number: ");
stageCode = input.nextLine();

if (stageCode.equals("24231"));
{
    if(randomChunk == 0)
    {
        System.out.println("Data Chunk found! Please wait...");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        System.out.println("Chunk 1/6:");
        System.out.println("text");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        System.out.println("");
        gateMethod();

    }
    else if(randomChunk == 1)
    {
        System.out.println("Data Chunk found! Please wait...");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        System.out.println("Chunk 2/6;");
        System.out.println("text");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        System.out.println("");
        gateMethod();

    }
    else if(randomChunk == 2)
    {
        System.out.println("Data Chunk found! Please wait...");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        System.out.println("Chunk 3/6:");
        System.out.println("text");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        System.out.println("");
        gateMethod();
    }
    else if(randomChunk == 3)
    {
        System.out.println("Data Chunk found! Please wait...");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        System.out.println("Chunk 4/6:");
        System.out.println("text");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        System.out.println("");
        gateMethod();   
    }
    else if(randomChunk == 4)
    {
        System.out.println("Data Chunk found! Please wait...");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        System.out.println("Chunk 5/6:");
        System.out.println("text");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        System.out.println("");
        gateMethod();   
    }
    else if(randomChunk == 5)
    {
        System.out.println("Data Chunk found! Please wait...");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        System.out.println("Chunk 6/6:");
        System.out.println("text");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        System.out.println("");
        gateMethod();   
    }
}
if (stageCode.equals("75832"));
{
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Data correct! Please wait...");
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    System.out.println("text");
    System.out.println("more text");
}
```

}

Comment: While I try to work it out, just a tip, you could cut out that whole big if/else if chunk using `System.out.println("Chunk " + (randomChunk + 1) + "/6;");`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the semicolon from the end of this line:

```
if (stageCode.equals("24231"));
```

and from this line:

```
if (stageCode.equals("75832"));
```

Java will treat the semicolon as the entire body of the `if` condition here.  Then the block in braces following it will always be executed, because it's not attached to the `if` condition as you expected it to be.

Comment: This is the second similar situation I've seen posted here in the last couple weeks.  Is there a compiler option that detects this potential error and displays a warning?  If so, maybe we should encourage people to use it.  If not, maybe we should encourage someone to add one!!

Comment: @ajb I don't think there's a compiler option for that, but a good IDE should detect it.  IntelliJ IDEA detects these cases this way by highlighting the `if` as a warning and remarking `'if' statement has empty body`.

Comment: Checkstyle or pmd or findbugs.